# Merging consecutive entries that share the same headline

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I've been trying to achieve the following:

```
* Riviere
Contents of Riviere title

* Riviere 
More contents of Riviere
```

turn into:

```
* Riviere
Contents of Riviere title
More contents of Riviere
```

I found a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47009378/org-mode-export-filter-all-headlines-matching-pattern-and-promote-subheaders) that almost gets the job done. I tried adding a `heading2` variable and changing the condition to match `heading` and `heading2`:

```
(defun promote-screenings-and-readings (&optional backend)
  (org-map-entries
   (lambda ()
     (let ((point (point))
           (heading (buffer-substring-no-properties
                     (point)
                     (save-excursion
                       (forward-line)
                       (point))))
           (heading2 (save-excursion
                       (org-backward-heading-same-level 1)
                       (forward-line))))
       (when (or (string= heading heading2))
         (org-map-entries
          (lambda ()
            (unless (= (point) point)
              (org-promote)))
          nil 'tree)
         (forward-line)
         (delete-region point (point)))))))
```

But it still doesn't work. That's how I set `heading2`, right? If I change `string= heading "* Anything here\n"` the heading gets deleted.

The reason behind this is I keep all my college slides inside an org file, and I want to avoid repetitive headlines when exporting to something other than Beamer. There are 5k lines in the document, so I think using the `:no_title:` method would be inefficient.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but wanted to point out that there are built-in functions to get the heading, such as `org-heading-components` and elements thereof can be obtained using the function `nth` and the corresponding `N`.  See also `org-element-at-point`; e.g., to get the title, `(let* ((element (org-element-at-point)) (title (org-element-property :raw-value element))) title)`.  I personally like to programmatically go to the bottom of an `org-mode` file and search backwards, using something like `(while (re-search-backward org-complex-heading-regexp nil t) ...)`

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: ... continued from my initial comment:  And here is another example of how to get the contents of a heading when point is at the beginning thereof:  `(when (looking-at org-complex-heading-regexp) (let ((stars (match-string-no-properties 1)) (status (match-string-no-properties 2)) (priority (match-string-no-properties 3)) (title (match-string-no-properties 4)) (tags (match-string-no-properties 5))) (list stars status priority title tags)))`  And, to get the whole kitten kaboodle, match `0`; e.g., `(when (looking-at org-complex-heading-regexp) (match-string-no-properties 0))` ...

Comment: @lawlist, I used org-element previously and understand what you're telling but I don't quite follow how you get the element at a point and then the element after OR before it. Doing recursively as you suggested would be optimal I think. What I don't get is how I get element at point and the element before it to compare both strings. I will try to recover the point in the second var in let and try to go to previous heading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To merge all subtrees/entries that share the same headline, you can try the following:

```lisp
(defun merge-subtrees ()
  (interactive)
  (let (headlines)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward org-complex-heading-regexp nil t)
        (let ((headline (match-string 4)))
          (if (member headline headlines)
              (let* ((beg (line-beginning-position))
                     (end (save-excursion (org-end-of-subtree)))
                     (contents (buffer-substring (point) end)))
                (delete-region beg (save-excursion
                                     (org-end-of-subtree t t)))
                (save-excursion
                  (when (re-search-backward (concat "^\\*.?+ "
                                                    headline
                                                    "\\($\\|[ \t]+:.+\\)")
                                            nil t)
                    (org-end-of-subtree)
                    (insert contents))))
            (push headline headlines)))))))
```

Now to merge only consecutive subtrees/entries that share the
same headline, try the following:

```lisp
(defun merge-subtrees ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (while (re-search-backward org-complex-heading-regexp nil t)
      (let ((headline (match-string 4)))
        (when (save-excursion
                (outline-previous-heading)
                (and (looking-at org-complex-heading-regexp)
                     (string= headline (match-string 4))))
          (let ((beg (org-entry-beginning-position))
                (end (save-excursion
                       (org-end-of-meta-data t)
                       (point))))
            (when (> beg (point-min))
              (delete-region beg end))))))))
```

Comment: Sorry for late answer. How to modify so it just merges if it's directly below it? Thanks for taking your time to help me

Comment: @cadr I changed the answer. See if that works for you.

Comment: Yes! It works! Thank you so much, sincerely, I thought my approach was close enough but you and @lawlist came up with total different solution. It always delete the first entry due to the recursion form. If you are in the first heading and do (outline-previous-heading), the point stays in the same position and it gets flushed. I just added a if statement around the when case: `(if (not (string-match (what-line) "(Line 1)"))`. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @cadr, thanks. I see the problem. Should be fixed now.

Comment: The first implementation instead of merging same headlines makes infinite copies of chosen headlines until I break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer does not modify the original `org-mode` buffer containing the raw data, but instead gathers the raw data into a list and then generates a new buffer containing a modified version of the original data.  My personal preference is to go to the bottom of the working buffer and search backwards -- this is because point is at the beginning of a heading at each stop of the `re-...` search.  [There is a line of code that uses `nreverse` on the initial `gathered-data` because we searched from the bottom of the file to the top of the file -- the assumption is that the original raw data contained a desired order, whether that be chronological or something else.]  It is, of course, possible to search forward with a modified version of this example ... it is also possible to sort the data ..., but that is beyond the scope of this example.

**TEST DATA -- ORG-MODE BUFFER**:

```
* Baz is the best.
Testing ten eleven twelve.

* Riviere had a cup of tea.
Contents of Riviere title.

* Foo is having toast.
Testing one two three.

* Bar had a baby.
Testing seven eight nine.

* Riviere had a cup of tea.
More contents of Riviere.

* Baz is the best.
Testing thirteen fourteen fifteen.

* Foo is having toast.
Testing four five six.
```

**EXAMPLE CODE**:

```lisp
(save-excursion
  (unless (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
    (error "This example only works with an 'org-mode buffer."))
  (goto-char (point-max))
  (let ((kill-ring nil)
        (kill-ring-yank-pointer nil)
        (interprogram-cut-function nil)
        (interprogram-paste-function nil)
        gathered-result
        end-result)
    (while (re-search-backward org-complex-heading-regexp nil t)
      (let ((entire-heading (match-string 0))
            subtree)
          (org-copy-subtree)
          (setq subtree (car kill-ring))
        (push (list (cons entire-heading subtree)) gathered-result)))
    (setq gathered-result (nreverse gathered-result))
    (mapc
      (lambda (x)
        (if (= 0 (length end-result))
          (push x end-result)
          (let (test)
            (setq end-result (mapcar
                               (lambda (y)
                                 (if (equal (car (car x)) (car (car y)))
                                   (progn
                                     (setq test t)
                                     (append x y))
                                   y))
                               end-result))
            (when (null test)
              (push x end-result)))))
      gathered-result)
    (let ((buffer (get-buffer-create "*OUTPUT*")))
      (with-current-buffer buffer
        (unless (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
          (org-mode))
        (let ((buffer-read-only nil))
          (erase-buffer)
          (mapc
            (lambda (z)
              (if (= 1 (length z))
                (let ((string (replace-regexp-in-string "\n+$" "" (cdr (car z)))))
                  (insert string "\n\n"))
                (let ((string (replace-regexp-in-string "\n+$" "" (car (car z)))))
                  (insert string "\n"))
                (mapc
                  (lambda (w)
                    (let ((string (replace-regexp-in-string (concat "^" (car w) "\n") "" (cdr w))))
                      (setq string (replace-regexp-in-string "\n+$" "" string))
                      (insert string "\n")))
                  z)
                (insert "\n")))
            end-result)))
      (unless (get-buffer-window buffer)
        (display-buffer buffer t)))
    end-result))
```

**`*OUTPUT*` BUFFER -- USING EXAMPLE CODE**:

```
* Bar had a baby.
Testing seven eight nine.

* Riviere had a cup of tea.
Contents of Riviere title.
More contents of Riviere.

* Baz is the best.
Testing ten eleven twelve.
Testing thirteen fourteen fifteen.

* Foo is having toast.
Testing one two three.
Testing four five six.
```

Comment: Sorry for late answer. How to modify so it just merges if it's directly below it? Thanks for taking your time to help me

Comment: In general, I do not give examples involving `delete-region` -- out of fear that the O.P. or other forum reader in the future may not take appropriate backup measures and delete original data that is permanently lost ....